# как передавать разные экземпляры фрагментов в конструктор?

Tags: android, android-fragment

есть конструктор класса StatusRequest

```
public StatusRequest(final Fragment1 frag, final Activity cont) {
        this.context = cont;
        this.fragment = frag;
        this.myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

в данный конструктор передеается экземпляр Fragment1, как его можно исправить чтобы можно было передавать различные фрагменты? пробовал что-то типа такого

```
 public StatusRequest(final Fragment<T>, final Activity cont) {
            this.context = cont;
            this.fragment = frag;
            this.myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        }
```

но видимо не верно. подскажите как правильно?

Comment: Смотря что Вы хотите далее делать с полученным фрагментом. Передать-то можно просто `public StatusRequest(Fragment frag,` и передавайте любой.

Comment: @VAndrJ если описывать полностью, то у меня StatusRequest выполняет обращение к серверу, получает данные, и обрабатывает их. естесственно я хочу сделать так чтобы был 1 класс для запросов, и в нем уже обрабатывать ответы. и я передаю экземпляр и через него вызываю метод из переданного фрагмента, для перехода к следующему фрагменту, убираю progress dialog...

Comment: Думаю, это легче сделать при помощи интерфейса. Но если хотите передавать фрагмент - тогда как в ответе Андроид Андроид

Comment: @VAndrJ  можете показать как должно выглядеть  при помощи интерфейса?

Comment: @VAndrJ извините, если не по теме вопроса, но такой вопрос. я гоняю данные с сервера на сервер, получаю информацию, как мне можно сделать так чтоб прописать для этого ответа, используй этот метод? для другого другой? сейчас я обхожусь проверкой  полей типа if (row1==0) {..}else if (row2==0){..} , где ... - это выполняемые методы, просто, мне кажется, это не совсем верно и при наличии десятков запросов и ответов, код будет неподъемным. как это улучшить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте создать класс и назвать его, скажем `BaseFragment`. Унаследуйте его от `Fragment`, после чего все ваши фрагменты в свою очередь унаследуйте от `BaseFragment`. 
В конструкторе передавайте уже  `public StatusRequest(BaseFragment baseFragment)` 
По идее так должно сработать

Comment: а что в BaseFragment прописывать? не оставлять же его пустым?

Comment: @Сергей, абстрактные (а может и не абстрактные, зависит от логики) методы, которые Вам необходимы.

Comment: Собственно BaseFragment, вроде, и не нужен... Можно просто супер-класс всех фрагментов, т.е. Fragment в качестве типа аргумента указать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, то есть так? public StatusRequest(Fragment frag)

Comment: @Сергей, да, всё верно